# how to place plugin files in phonegap project?

Tags: cordova, plugins

I am using phonegap3.5. i installed plugin for email composer and creats files in my plugin folder. now my quetion is where i have to places these files. fyi here is list of folders which created by plugin
plugin/pluginname/www
plugin/pluginname/src
plugin/pluginname/plugin.xml
plugin/pluginname/

Answer (score 0):

See documentation... Here is the topic about adding plugins to a project: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/plugin_ref_plugman.md.html#Using%20Plugman%20to%20Manage%20Plugins

Comment: i already installed plugin. i have mentioned file as well which plugman installed in plugin director

Comment: if my plugin name will be emailcomposser and project name is xyc then what will be plugman path?

Comment: Are you using this one: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer ?

Comment: It's complicated to help you more without knowing exactly what you did: your question is not clear. What do you mean by "I installed the plugin", by "creats files in my plugin folder". Did you use CLI? ...